# select statement oracle sql

Tags: oracle, select

I have been having troubles with select statement within one table

the table has `emp_id`, `name` and `mgr_id`
the question is how to view the name of the employee that has mgr and then view the mgr's name within it

basically employee has the a mgr and the manager is listed within the same table no idea how to make it done

the output should be something like this:

```
Name of Employee        Name of the Manager
________________        ___________________
name 1                  name mgr
name 2                  name mgr
```

help would be highly appreciated

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self join:

```
SELECT    e.name AS name, m.name AS manager_name
FROM      emp e
LEFT JOIN emp m ON e.mgr_id = m.emp_id
```

Note the usage of a `left join` so employees without managers (supposedly the CEO) won't be excluded.

Comment: this works perfect, thanks for the advice gotta go more serious about join's u saved my day @Mureinik